# How to order a list of objects by the size of an value in the object in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of "Result" objects: result

which has a String: string

and a int: value

I am trying to order the list of objects in increasing size of result.getValue().

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Result>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Result r1, Result r2) {
        return r1.getValue() - r2.getValue();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could write a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compares the `Result` objects based on the result of `getValue()`, and then use [`Collections.sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)) to sort the `ArrayList`.